# Remote service with aidl file : ServiceConnection never called

Tags: android, aidl

I 'd like to bind 2 applications through a service with aidl file.

In my application A (with service that will be accessed) :

→aidl file (BillingInterface.aidl):

```
package com.A.service;
import android.os.Bundle;

interface BillingInterface {
    Bundle getServiceDetails(String a, String b);
}
```

Java interface is automatically created without troubles.

Then, my service that will be remoted:

```
public class BillingService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = BillingService.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return new BillingInterface.Stub() {    

            @Override
            public Bundle getServiceDetails(String a, String b)
                throws RemoteException {

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("test", "simple test");
                return b;
            };
        }
    }

}
```

In my manifest file :

```
<service
        android:name=".service.BillingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":remote" 

        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name=".service.BillingInterface.aidl" />
        </intent-filter>
/>
```

In my application B, I try to connect to it (I have the same aidl file):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.A", "com.A.service.BillingService");

    try {

    Boolean ret = bindService(i, mConnection , Context.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND );
    Log.d("DEBUG", ret.toString());  // will return "true"

    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("DEBUG", "not able to bind ! ");
    }


...


private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){


    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundService) {
        service = BillingInterface.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundService);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "onServiceConnected() : OK ");
    }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            service = null;
        }
    };



    //When clicking button :

    public void onclick(View v) {

        try {

            // serviceのcheckTransfertメッソードを呼ぶ
            Bundle response = service.getServiceDetails("test", "test");

            Log.d("DEBUG", response.getString("test"));

        } catch (RemoteException e) {

            Log.e("DEBUG", "error in RemoteExpcetion" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

When binding to service (bindService), I get a boolean "true", but method onServiceConnected in my serviceConnection is never called. I have set a button in order to call service's method (see above method "onclick"). If I click i get the below message :

```
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at com.example.testconnection/xxxx.MainActivity.onclick(MainActivity.java:59)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     ... 11 more
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 02:00:32.895: E/AndroidRuntime(3066):     ... 15 more
```

Any ideas ? 
Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
  Boolean ret = bindService(i, mConnection , Context.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND );
```

to:

```
Boolean ret = bindService(i, mConnection , Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
```

then onServiceConnected  will be called.

Comment: It works like a charm ! I've also changed package name in my appli B to avoid security error (java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface) . Thank you Lumos ~